# Quasi-syntomic descent and prismatic F-crystals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, p-adic-hodge-theory, descent

I am reading Bhatt and Scholze's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.14735)  on F-crystals, and they seem to be using the following result in the proof of Theorem 5.6:
let $X \to Y$ be a quasisyntomic cover of formal schemes over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (maybe with some extra assumptions), then to give a map $\epsilon \to \epsilon'$ of vector bundles on the prismatic site $X_\Delta$ (say with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}_\Delta$) is the same as giving a map $\epsilon|Y \to \epsilon'|Y$ on $Y_\Delta$ such that the two pullbacks along the projections $Y \times_{X} Y \to Y$ agree.

I am not sure what exactly quasi-syntomic descent means here, my guess is that given a cover of final of object of $Y_\Delta$, its pullback to $X_\Delta$ is also a cover of the final object, and then it reduces to a statement of descent of vector bundles along a quasi-syntomic map of rings. The problem is that I don't really know what the precise statement of that result would be. I've tried looking at their paper on Topological Hochschild Homology, but they don´t mention it explicitly.

As a whole papers working with prisms and integral p-adic Hodge theory use a variety of descent theorems that are not usually stated. They are most likely well-known to the experts, but I don´t have much experience with them. I would appreciate a reference for a more expository treatment of the general techniques involved in these descent theorems.

Comment: This is basically Proposition 2.14, which says that vector bundles over the prismatic site could be identified with vector bundles over the prismatic sheaf on the quasisyntomic site, and the later satisfies the quasisyntomic descent.